# R class is missing from my android project

Tags: android

I have a problem with R class from my android app. This class is missing from my project. So far I have done:
 Project -> Clean
 Right click on my project -> Android tools - > fix project properties
 I restart my IDE and did again the same things but the R class it still missing.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: try to rebuild your project

Comment: surely there is some error in xlm ...if not restart ur Visit eclipse

Comment: I already did this but the R class is still missing

Comment: In the project menu have you checked Build Automatically. If it is you might have an error during compilation. R class file is not generated have a look at "Problems" tab .

Comment: Thanks! I had an image name wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have an error inside your Java code so the project cannot be rebuilt. Try searching for the problem in Eclipse's "Error Log" and "Problems" tabs.

Answer (score 2):

```
**Just chek the "layout" or may be the "drawable" under "res" or may be values hav some thing wrong.
Coz its the reason the R mapping class. 
Then u will find it.if not for help see the Logcat tab or problems tab it will help u.
after that clean and build. or build automatically**
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project and click *Properties*. In the left Pane, click on **JAVA COMPILER**, and then in the right pane, set **compiler compliance level at 1.6**. IF that doesn't help, Import project again and then try to Run.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit complex, but R will not create if you have some error in your java file while finding resources . Mostly when you are trying to attach an xml view or layout into your java code(Usually if you have misspelled any resource id). Try to go few steps back if you recently added a view, or find the exact place by referring your logs or problems tab. Then clean the project again...hope it helps....